# QAbstractButton Image stretches over full width of the column

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am subclassing QAbstractButton class to create a clickable icon that accesses user files. I did this following this tutorial here: https://coolchevy.org.ua/2016/06/20/basic-example-how-to-code-a-image-button-in-pyqt/

The only problem I am running into is the QAbsractButton size. I am adding it as a Widget to a QGridLayout. On the grid, it is right above a button with a greater width. The image takes the size of the column and stretches as shown here

[image]

Is there a way to adjust the size of QAbstractButton before it is added to the screen? I have tried .setMaximumWidth, but it doesn't have the method.

Update w/ code

```
def init_ui(self):
    self.settings_button=QPushButton("Email settings")
    self.templates_button=TemplateButton(QPixmap('templates.png'))
    self.layout.addWidget(self.templates_button,0,4)
    self.layout.addWidget(self.settings_button,1,4)`

class TemplateButton(QAbstractButton):
    def __init__(self,pixmap):
        super(TemplateButton, self).__init__()
        self.pixmap = pixmap

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        pix = self.pixmap
        if self.isDown():
            print("Click")
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(event.rect(), pix)

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.update()
    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.update()
    def sizeHint(self):
        return QSize(50,50)
```

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: @eyllanesc I updated it with the relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case we must establish the size policy for the widget, using the method [`setSizePolicy()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#sizePolicy-prop), The [policies](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsizepolicy.html#Policy-enum) that can be established are as follows:

> **QSizePolicy::Fixed**: The QWidget::sizeHint() is the only acceptable alternative, so the widget can never grow or shrink (e.g. the vertical direction of a push button).
>
> **QSizePolicy::Minimum**: The sizeHint() is minimal, and sufficient. The widget can be expanded, but there is no advantage to it being larger (e.g. the horizontal direction of a push button). It cannot be smaller than the size provided by sizeHint().
>
> **QSizePolicy::Maximum**: The sizeHint() is a maximum. The widget can be shrunk any amount without detriment if other widgets need the space (e.g. a separator line). It cannot be larger than the size provided by sizeHint().
>
> **QSizePolicy::Preferred**: The sizeHint() is best, but the widget can be shrunk and still be useful. The widget can be expanded, but there is no advantage to it being larger than sizeHint() (the default QWidget policy).
>
> **QSizePolicy::Expanding**: The sizeHint() is a sensible size, but the widget can be shrunk and still be useful. The widget can make use of extra space, so it should get as much space as possible (e.g. the horizontal direction of a horizontal slider).
>
> **QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding**: The sizeHint() is minimal, and sufficient. The widget can make use of extra space, so it should get as much space as possible (e.g. the horizontal direction of a horizontal slider).
>
> **QSizePolicy::Ignored**  The sizeHint() is ignored. The widget will get as much space as possible.

he policies that the Widgets have by default is `QSizePolicy::Preferred`, but in your case you should use `QSizePolicy::Fixed`. In addition you must establish the alignment to be centered, so that from the above you get the following:

```
self.settings_button=QPushButton("Email settings")
self.templates_button=TemplateButton(QPixmap('qt_extended_48x48.png'))
self.templates_button.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Fixed, QSizePolicy.Fixed)
self.layout.addWidget(self.templates_button,0,4, Qt.AlignCenter)
self.layout.addWidget(self.settings_button,1,4)
```

Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It works and now I know how to size QAbstractButtons ++